# What if someone accuses another person of killing him in his last statement before death

Tags: indian-penal-code, indian-constitutional-law

Suppose, Person X has some minor feud with person A.

If X sets himself on fire and accuses A of killing him (last statement before legal authorities) and later dies.

Will last statement of deceased work as criteria to punish accused A?

How does last statement weigh against evidences?

Don't go in the matter whether it was a suicide or murder. Point of question is about *last statement of deceased*.

Please mention respective law prevalent in India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "punish" **A** there must be evidence that would convince the court beyond reasonable doubt.

The last statement will be just a piece of admissible evidence. Just by itself it will certainly not be enough to prove **A**'s guilt, but it may add weight if there are other corroborating pieces of evidence e.g. witnesses saying that **X** indeed killed themselves because **A** made them do so etc.

Comment: The tags specify India. I'm not an expert, but do they still have juty trials?

Comment: @o.m. Good point, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: ISTR that some jurisdictions gave deathbed statements extra weight, somewhere between "no more self-interest" and an archaic "dying in a state of grace." Where does India fall on that?

Comment: @o.m. That's why deathbed statements are admissible at all (unlike hearsay) but they don't carry any extra special weight than other admissible evidence. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dying_declaration